# How can I return part of a Python circular stream to a web page as video

Tags: python, video, stream, raspberry-pi

I am using [picamera](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/index.html) to record video to a circular stream. How can I show part of the video (from frame a to frame b) on a web page?

As web server, I am using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html). In the web page I am using the video tag, with the URL to a bottle route as src. I cannot find any examples on how to do this.

Here is sample code of what I am trying to do:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, request
import picamera

app = Bottle()
camera = picamera.PiCamera(framerate = 30)
stream = picamera.PiCameraCircularIO(camera, seconds=600)
camera.start_recording(stream, format = 'h264')

@app.route('/view')
def view():
    filename = request.query.filename
    print("View video file: " + filename)
    res = '''
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>View video</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <video width="640" height="480" controls>
                    <source src="http://10.0.0.14:8080/video?fromframe=30&toframe=330" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''
    return(res)

@app.route('/video')
def video() :
    fromFrame = request.query.fromframe
    toFrame = request.query.toframe
    print("Sending from fram " + str(fromFrame) + " to frame " + str(toFrame))
    return "WHAT DO I DO HERE?"

run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

It is at the end of the video() function I don't know what to do. And of cours, I am not totally sure of the rest either.